# check if $index in ng-repeat is null

Tags: angularjs, gridview, ionic-framework

I have a grid view with two grids per row. This is the code:

```
  <ion-content scroll="true" class="has-header">
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="i in products">
        <div class="row" ng-if="$even">
          <div class="col col-50">
            <a class="item item-thumbnail-center" href="#">
              <img src="http://{{host}}/{{
              products[$index].prod_img
              }}" class="img-thumbnail">
              <h2>{{products[$index].prod_name}}</h2>
              <p>Php {{products[$index].prod_price}}.00</p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-50" ng-if="$index + 1">
            <a class="item item-thumbnail-center" href="#">
              <img src="http://{{host}}/{{
              products[$index + 1].prod_img
              }}" class="img-thumbnail">
              <h2>{{products[$index + 1].prod_name}}</h2>
              <p>Php {{products[$index + 1].prod_price}}.00</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

`controller.js`

```
  $http.get("http://"+ $scope.host +"/mobile/get_products.php?cat_id=" + $stateParams.cat_id)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.products = response.data;
  });
```

The problem is when the size of the array products is an odd, the second grid in the last row still shows up and certainly no item is displayed in there because the item is specified by the index is null. I've found some other solution on how to make this by configuring the array right from the controller but I want to ask if there is any way to check using an angular directive whether $index is null, and if true, the grid will be hidden.

Comment: you are going in wrong way dont use `$index+1` it will never work

Comment: show your js code

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal but apparently it is working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use *ng-class* directive and put a css class which will get true when products[$index] === null | products[$index+1] === null. it will be like

```
    ng-class={'hide-row': products[$index] === null | products[$index+1] === null}
```

where css

```
    .hide-row{ display : none;}
```

Comment: I guess this solution is fine.